# I need pass two arguments to controller from view in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

Like the title says, I need send two variables to my controller from my blade, but when I do, I have the error below

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::show(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected
```

My link in blade:

```
<a href="{{ route('projects.show', [$project->slug, $project->id]) }}" class="card--project waypoint">
```

My method´s controller show:

```
public function show($slug, $id)
{
    $project_id = Project::where('id', $id);

    $reviews = File::all()->where('fileable_id', '==', $project_id);
    $chart = Charts::database($reviews, 'bar', 'highcharts')
              ->title("Detalle de revisiones")
              ->elementLabel("Revisiones")
              ->dimensions(1000, 500)
              ->responsive(true)
              ->template('indigo-material')
              ->groupByDay()
              ->groupBy('responsable');

    $project = Project::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $comments = Comment::orderBy('id', 'ASC');
    $files = File::orderBy('id', 'ASC');
    return view('projects.show', compact('project', 'comments', 'files', 'chart'));
}
```

How I can send two valid arguments to controller from a view?

Comment: What is your route

Comment: Route::get('projects/{id}', 'ProjectController@show')->name('projects.show')
  ->middleware('permission:projects.show');

Comment: Your route should be `Route::get('projects/{slug}/{id}', 'ProjectController@show')->name('projects.show')->middleware('permission:projects.show');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**your route should be like this**

```
Route::get('projects/{id}/{slug}', 'ProjectController@show')->name('projects.show')
        ->middleware('permission:projects.show');
```

***explanation***
because mainly you declared two parameters in you function your function expecting two parameters but you only passing the id  because your route declaration allow you only to pass id 
hope it works with you